# Custom Windows Authentication Package Logon Failed

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-authentication, winlogon, local-security-authority

I have developed custom authentication package that I would like to use for interactive logon. It creates the access token in the `LsaApUserLogon` function.

When I call `LsaUserLogon` from an application I can enumerate new user sessions, but when I used it for logon (also I have created a custom credential provider) I can see in Windows Event log that I was successfully logged in and then logged out.

When I select my specific Credential and try to logon, it enters into `LsaApLogonUser` API of my Authentication Package. If I check log file, `LsaApLogonUser` return `STATUS_SUCCESS`. But Windows is not logged on. After leaving `LsaAPLogonUser`, LSA calls `LsaApLogonTerminated` API and back `LogonUI`.

When I prepared the `TokenInformation` I got `LookupPrivilegeValueW` failed for the `SeInteractiveLogonRight`. I don't know if this is important for logon.

```
LsaApLogonUser(...){
    ......
    // NetUserGetInfo

    // AllocateLocallyUniqueId (LogonId)

    err = GetTokenInformationv2(pdi?pdi->DomainControllerName:NULL,wszDomain,wszUser,&LocalTokenInformation,LogonId);

    err = g_pSec->CreateLogonSession(LogonId);      

    if(ProfileBuffer)
    {
        *ProfileBuffer=NULL;
        *ProfileBufferLength=0;
    }

    (*TokenInformationType)=LsaTokenInformationV2;
    (*TokenInformation)=LocalTokenInformation;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

GetTokenInformationv2(...){
    ....
    ....
    // Call LsaEnumerateAccountRights 
    // check LookupPrivilegeValueW // It failed for "SeInteractiveLogonRight"
    // 
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is `ProfileBuffer` important for logon? I don't know why LSA cannot logon.

Comment: While rights and privileges are usually interchangeable, I believe this is one of the cases where they aren't.  Rights aren't added to the user's token, so presumably aren't needed in the TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure.  I can confirm that (as documented) LookupPrivilegeValue does not work for SeInteractiveLogonRight.  Presumably, LsaApLogonUser is instead expected to validate the user's right to logon itself.

Comment: As for the profile buffer, the documentation doesn't say that you can set it to `NULL` so I would recommend creating a buffer as documented.  Give it a reasonable size, say 32 bytes, and fill it with zeros.  Once you've got it all working, you can experiment with this again.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, thanks, I have solved my problem. 
profile buffer must be allocated with a minimum size(1byte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation does not say that the profile buffer can be set to `NULL` and it seems that it is indeed mandatory.  The OP reports that allocating and returning a profile buffer (just a single byte was enough) resolved the problem.  [Addendum: see the comment by Nehluxhes below, who reports that the buffer needs to contain valid data.]

The error when attempting to retrieve a LUID for `SeInteractiveLogonRight` was not relevant; the user's logon rights do not need to be included in the `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES` structure, so no LUID is needed, and as documented, the `LookupPrivilegeValue` function only accepts privileges:

> The LookupPrivilegeValue function supports only the privileges specified in the Defined Privileges section of Winnt.h.

(Note that the relevant section of `winnt.h` only contains definitions for SeXxxPrivilege; the definitions for SeXxxLogonRight are in `ntsecapi.h`.)

Comment: From my experience returning just a single byte is not sufficient, you need to return a proper MSV1_0_INTERACTIVE_PROFILE or KERB_INTERACTIVE_PROFILE.
Wasted a *lot* of time on this.